# PHP: What does mcrypt_decrypt() return on failure

Tags: php, mcrypt

PHP `mcrypt_decrypt()` is defined as

```
string mcrypt_decrypt ( string $cipher , string $key , string $data , 
                        string $mode [, string $iv ] )
```

If the `$data` is not a valid `mcrypt_encrypt`ed string what will be the return value ?

I'm using PHP 5.5.9.

I have seen that PHP 5.6.0 have included `Return FALSE on failure`.

But how to detect a failure in previous PHP versions ?

Comment: My guess is it returns `false`, and they just forgot to say so in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to 5.6.0, a failure [will return `false`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php#refsect1-function.mcrypt-decrypt-returnvalues). You are misreading the changelog:

> Invalid `key` and `iv` sizes are no longer accepted. `mcrypt_decrypt()` will now throw a warning and return `FALSE` **if the inputs are invalid.**

Answer (score 0):

"Failure" and "not a valid `mcrypt_encrypt`ed string" are not the same thing ...

A failure may be using an unsupported algorithm/mode, an internal error in libmcrypt or PHP itself, etc. In that case - it will return FALSE.

However, there's not really such thing as an invalid encrypted string - that's not something that can be detected when using an unauthenticated cipher mode (and mcrypt doesn't support the ones that come with built-in authentication).

Instead, you should verify the cipherText's validity yourself and that must happen *before* you pass it to `mcrypt_decrypt()`. You do that by using a MAC, which is a long topic to cover in itself, so you should really google it ...